# $scope.value changes only after second click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

There is my html code:

```
<div ng-if="user.type == 'none'"> <button ng-click="selectUserType('user')"></button> </div>
<div ng-if="user.type !== 'none'"> //here goes input etc </div>
```

There is my script:

```
$scope.user = {type: 'none'};
$scope.selectUserType = function(type) {
 $location.path('/signup/'+type);
 $scope.user.type = type;
};
```

The problem is that after first click in console I see that $scope.user gains 'user' value, then right in the moment backs to 'none', but the location changes to what I need. $scope.user gains again needed value after a second click, and hides useful block and shows what is needed.

How can I do it maybe in another way? I need to do all those by one click

it works when I remove `$location.path('/signup/'+type)` , but I still need to change my location.path when user.type is changed

Sorry for my English, if you see some grammar mistakes or something. it is not my native, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure here you need '</button>' tag: <div ng-if="user.type !== 'none'> //here goes input etc <button> </div>? Seems like you lost it here?

Comment: Have you tried setting `$scope.user.type` before changing `$location.path`? Also your button tag isn't closing. Stranger things have caused stranger behavior ;) `<button ng-click="selectUserType('user')><button>`.

Comment: sorry, there was some mistakes, now it's have right look

Comment: @JanS sure, i tried, same reaction

Comment: Both ng-if directives are missing a closing quote. Did you copy/paste the code in to your post or freehand type it? I'm guessing you just typed it in or you likely wouldn't even be able to see the button in your browser. Are you certain this is the *exact* code you are using?

Comment: Im leaning toward a Async Problem... And can you provide us with a plunkr? : http://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: You should  also close the ng-if="user.type == 'none'", both of them

Comment: yes, I freehanded this, and yes, exactly code that I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on a way, Dmitriy Loskutov answered me, I used this:
just check location.path in start of the controller, then set the type:

```
    var locPath = $location.path();
    if (locPath == '/signup') {
        $scope.user = {type: 'none'};
    } else if (locPath == '/signup/user') {
        $scope.user = {type: 'user'};
    }

    $scope.selectUserType = function(type) {
        $location.path('/signup/' + type);
        $scope.user.type = type;
    };
```

hope, that helps someone, cause i've lost about 4 hours to get this simple solution >_<

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (this is not the best way):

```
var $user = {type: 'none'}; // define OUTSIDE of controller(or link function)
```

Code inside your controller(or link function)

```
$scope.user = $user;
$scope.selectUserType = function(type) {
    $location.path('/signup/' + type);
    $user.type = type;
    $scope.user = angular.extend({}, $user);
};
```

I guess your controller init twice in your case, so try to define $user variable outside of controller, for example in global scope(also you can try to define it in $rootScope), so when the controller reinit it is does not chage $user variable.

Comment: Did you try to skip `$location.path('/signup/'+type);`? Maybe it is reinit your controller(or link function) and set `$scope.user = {type: 'none'};` again?

Comment: It works when i delete `$location.path('/signup/'+type);` normally, but I still need to change location.path

Comment: I've edited the answer. Try to init `$scope.user` by this value `$scope.user || {type: 'none'};`

Comment: same result, unfortunately

Comment: I've edited the answer :) try it. But this is a `bad way`, do not use it all the time :)

Comment: yes, it works, but it need to refresh the page, to get "welcome-look" on the page, btw thanks, mate

Comment: and you're god damn right about reiniting controller. I'll take a look for rewriting this. Great thanks!